# Nodal analysis using supernode tough problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis

Hi I am stuck on the following problem:
[image]

I know I have to use a supernode but I dont know where to put it.

Comment: I tried making a super node out of the independent voltage source and the dependent voltage source, but I didnt know how to solve for the part of the supernode connected to the ground node.

Comment: You don't need supernodes to do the analysis. Personally, I think it just makes you have to retain more memorized garbage in your head. Do you have to use them? Or are you allowed to just use simple, normal nodal?

Comment: @BasZ Can you show us some kind of partial approach that at least shows what you can put down on paper? Something? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

If a voltage source is referenced (directly or through other voltage sources) to ground then you **do not** need to make a supernode. You get the voltage at node D by inspection, and you can write an equation for node A with only a tiny bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to walk you though the nodal equations. I won't solve them; you can do that easily enough using any number of different free programs. But the nodal equations are trivial. (So trivial in fact that I'm writing them out by rote after only having 3 hrs sleep in more than the last 24 hours and practically drifting towards sleep right now.)

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_A}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_A}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+I_{2V_X}+\frac{V_A}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}&=\frac{V_B}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_C}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_E}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}\\\\
\frac{V_B}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_B}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+2\:\text{mA}&=\frac{V_A}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_C}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}\\\\
\frac{V_C}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_C}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_C}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}&=\frac{V_A}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_B}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_D}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+2\cdot I_X\\\\
\frac{V_D}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_D}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}&=\frac{V_C}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_E}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+I_{2V_X}+I_{12\:\text{V}}\\\\
\frac{V_E}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_E}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_E}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}&=\frac{V_A}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{V_D}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}\\\\
I_X&=\frac{V_B-V_C}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}\\\\
V_D&=12\:\text{V}\\\\
V_A&=V_D-2\cdot V_X\\\\
V_X&=V_E\\\\
I_0&=\frac{V_D-V_E}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}
\end{align*}$$

You can do some of the really easy substitutions indicated above (very obvious ones) and then simply solve the remaining simultaneous equations (which should be six equations and six unknowns if you leave \$V_D\$ as an unknown to be substituted in later on, or five equations and five unknowns if you just plug in the value of \$V_D\$, directly.)

Once you solve that, \$I_0\$ is trivial to compute.

Comment: Why is Vd = 12V , doesn't the dependent source influence it?

Comment: No, an ideal voltage source forces (absolute!) its voltage on its output.

Comment: @BasZ How can it? A fixed voltage source is not flexible. What is flexible is the current through it.